# tooltip is outside my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My tooltip is in the outside of my container, I can see that my tooltip cut.
I want to make my tooltip to be outside of the container, so that it would be totally visible.

I tried to change the z-index, overflow, and etc. However, nothing happens. 
I need your help please!

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/82p2b5eu/1/)

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
$(".nano").nanoScroller();
```

```css
/** initial setup **/
.nano {
  position : relative;
  width    : 200px;
  height   : 150px;
  overflow : hidden;
    
}
.action{
    width:100%;
    height:35px
}
.nano > .nano-content {
  position      : absolute;
  overflow      : scroll;
  overflow-x    : hidden;
  top           : 0;
  right         : 0;
  bottom        : 0;
  left          : 0;
  border : 1px solid red;
}
.nano > .nano-content:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}
.nano > .nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.has-scrollbar > .nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
}
.nano > .nano-pane {
  background : rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  position   : absolute;
  width      : 10px;
  right      : 0;
  top        : 0;
  bottom     : 0;
  visibility : hidden\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity    : .01;
  -webkit-transition    : .2s;
  -moz-transition       : .2s;
  -o-transition         : .2s;
  transition            : .2s;
  -moz-border-radius    : 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius : 5px;
  border-radius         : 5px;
}
.nano > .nano-pane > .nano-slider {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position              : relative;
  margin                : 0 1px;
  -moz-border-radius    : 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius : 3px;
  border-radius         : 3px;
}
.nano:hover > .nano-pane, .nano-pane.active, .nano-pane.flashed {
  visibility : visible\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity    : 0.99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS/master/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js"></script>

<div style="position: relative; left:100px;">
<div id="about" class="nano">
    <div class="nano-content"> 
    <ul class="list-first-steps">
        <li>
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"class="action">aaaaaaa</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"class="action">bbbbbbb</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"class="action">ccccccc</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"class="action">vvvvvvvv</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"class="action">ddddddd</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="action">aaaaaaa</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="action">eeeeeeeee</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="action">wwwwww</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="action">eeerr</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="action">errrrtte</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Sorry, I solve this problem ....

I init tooltip in javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'})
```

when I include `container:body` , I can see all tooltip.
Sorry for the question and I hope I can help everyone :P

edit:
[Jsfiddle answer](http://jsfiddle.net/82p2b5eu/2/)